# <iframe> not working in Android hybrid app made with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, iframe

I made an Android App using `PhoneGap` app by Adobe.

But `<iframe>` tag is not working. I googled about it, and they said, add this line to your `config.xml` file

```
    <allow-navigation href="http://example.com/" />
```

This is my full code of `config.xml` file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.phonegap.wmsiwt" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>What Movie Should I Watch Today</name>
    <description>
        A blank PhoneGap app.
    </description>
    <allow-navigation href="http://example.com.com/" />

    <author email="support@phonegap.com" href="http://phonegap.com">
        PhoneGap Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```